# WooCommerce Load and customize archive-product.php from my Plugin Folder

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

I am trying to load template files from `my-plugin` folder instead of using default woocommerce template. I want to customize the shop page base from `my-plugin` folder template structure, so i edit the `archive-product.php` to comment and check which display blank page or not but it load the default woocommerce template `(archive-product.php)`. I already moved the template files to the `my-plugin/woocommerce/` folder Here is my code i tried

```
 function cc_woocommerce_locate_template($template, $template_name, $template_path) {

        global $woocommerce;
        global $post;
        $plugin_path = untrailingslashit(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)) . '/woocommerce/';
    //returns my-plugin folder with base file name echo $plugin_path;
               //   echo $template_name;
            if (file_exists($plugin_path . $template_name)) {
                $template = $plugin_path . $template_name;
               // var_dump($template);
                return $template;
            }

        return $template;
    }
```

and the hook i pointed is

```
add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template', 'cc_woocommerce_locate_template', 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested the provided code and it runs without problems, so in such situations it is best to start over. Create a new plugin and paste the code below. It contains two filters:

> **wc_get_template_part** - for templates used in loop
>
> **woocommerce_locate_template**   - for all other templates

---

```
//
// get path for templates used in loop ( like content-product.php )
add_filter( 'wc_get_template_part', function( $template, $slug, $name ) 
{ 

    // Look in plugin/woocommerce/slug-name.php or plugin/woocommerce/slug.php
    if ( $name ) {
        $path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . WC()->template_path() . "{$slug}-{$name}.php";    
    } else {
        $path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . WC()->template_path() . "{$slug}.php";    
    }

    return file_exists( $path ) ? $path : $template;
    
}, 10, 3 );


// get path for all other templates.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', function( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) 
{ 

    $path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $template_path . $template_name;  
    return file_exists( $path ) ? $path : $template;
    
}, 10, 3 );
```

Now create a subfolder `woocommerce` inside the plugins main folder and copy inside original files `archive-product.php` and `content-product.php`. And finally, make some small modification ( echo something ) in that files just to see if they are loaded. I tested this example and templates are loaded with no problems in the following hierarchy:

> theme/template_path/template_name
>
> theme/template_name
>
> plugin/template_path/template_name
>
> default/template_name

Comment: OMG It works great :) But edited changes trigger only on content-product.php but not in archive-product.php

Comment: That's strange, if the function is launched then it's not a compatibility issue ( I'm using WC 2.1.5 ), maybe you have yet another plugin installed that overrides your plugin. Raise the priority of woocommerce_locate_template filter from 10 to let's say 100, and test again.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for archive-product.php or single-product.php load from plugin. I think it should work.

```
public function include_template_function( $template_path ) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'product' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'single-product.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'woocommerce/single-product.php';
            }
        }

        if ( is_archive() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'archive-product.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'woocommerce/archive-product.php';
            }
        }
    }
    _log($template_path);
    return $template_path;
}

add_filter( 'template_include', array($this, 'include_template_function' ), 100 );
```